# How do I bold a text and use a font in paste function in R

Tags: r, text, fonts, shiny

I would like to bold a text using the paste function. How do I code this in R? Thanks for looking into this.

```
observeEvent(input$submit3,{

if (input$submit3==0) return()

tagList(
  lapply(1:input$numoftrends, function(j) {
    trend.period <- input[[paste0("trendDateRange", j)]]
    trend1 <- substr(trend.period[1],1,7)
    trend2 <- substr(trend.period[2],1,7)

    output[[paste0('Text', j)]] <- renderText({
      #paste(" ")  ## add space in between text
      paste('Trend Date Range', j, ': ', trend1 ,' - ', trend2)
    })
  })
  )
})
```

Comment: Try pasting a `<b>` before what you want to bold and a `</b>` after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose your text with `<B>` and `</B>` and use `htmlOutput`:

```
library("shiny")
server <-function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste('<B>Trend Date Range</B>')
  })
}

ui <-fluidPage( htmlOutput("text"))

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in looking into this. As you can see in my code I am using an lapply to print several text. Now how do I put that in the fluidPage for the htmlOutput. I do apologise I am new to R and shiny. Have a great day!

Comment: Please don't worry about it. I got it. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry how about this code. How do I bold it?   paste('<B>Trend Date Range</B>', j, ': ', trend1 ,' - ', trend2)   I wan to bold all of these text in the code.

Comment: `paste('<B>Trend Date Range', j, ': ', trend1 ,' - ', trend2, '</B>')`